# WAVE file is not readable by Python's libraries

Tags: python, wave

I found out that some of my '.wav' files are badly written.
Given the following comparison between 'corrupted_file.wav' and 'ok_file.wav', this is what I get when i try to read 'corrupted_file.wav' using standard libraries such soundfile, wave, librosa etc.

> RuntimeError: Error opening 'corrupted_file.wav': File contains data in an unknown format.

So I tried to understand what was the issue using:

```
with open('corrupted_file.wav', 'rb') as audiofile:
    corrupted_f = audiofile.read()

with open('ok_file.wav', 'rb') as audiofile:
    ok_f = audiofile.read()

print(corrupted_f[:40])
print(ok_f[:40])
```

That's what I get:

```
b'\xff\xfb\x90\xc4\x00\x03\x12\xa9\xa3\x16g\xb0\xc9B\xf4\xb4e\xcd\x94\x9a8\x00\x12\x93\x95\xc5F~\x1e\xa71\xd2q\x18\xa58\xeb\x01\x82\x19'
b'RIFF$`\x08\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x80\xbb\x00\x00\x00\xee\x02\x00\x04\x00\x10\x00data'
```

As you can see, 'corrupted_file.wav' does not satisfy WAVE standards as it does not present relevant chunks as 'RIFF', 'WAVEfmt' and 'data'.
by the way Windows 10 is able to play it with its internal application.
If I use a standard audio converter to export 'corrupted_file.wav' as a WAVE file, I get 'converted_corrupted_file.wav' whose representation becomes:

```
b'RIFFF\x16\x11\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00D\xac\x00\x00\x10\xb1\x02\x00\x04\x00\x10\x00LIST\x1a\x00\x00\x00INFOISFT\x0e\x00\x00\x00Lavf59.27.100\x00data\x00\x16\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\...
```

Which for me is not easily linkable to the corrupted one, so I cannot recovery it with a homemade function.

I checked the file's format using several online tools and the result it's always the same: "does not match any of the known formats". But windows 10 is still able to decode and play it so I guess there should be a trick.

I could semi-manually map and move every corrupted file into a temporary folder so that I could import them into an audio converter that operates the conversion from '.wav' to '.wav'. Then I could move the new versions to their original position while deleting the corrupted counterparts.

But how can I automatically recover 'corrupted_file.wav' with a python written function? I need it as the amount of corrupted files is thousands.

Comment: It may still be an MP3 truncated at the beginning. To get more specific advice, attach the whole file to your question.

Comment: unfortunately I this is not possible anymore. I managed to map and move every corrupted file into a folder in order to manually import them into a converter and remove them to their original path actually deleting their corrupted counterpart :(

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an MP3 file (because it starts with `b'\xff'`). Rename it to file.mp3, use a tool to convert it to file.wav, and open file.wav from Python.

Comment: Good catch!  You can see the structure of a MP3 file here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I've already tried this strategy but renaming the corrupted with '.mp3' extension leads to the same 'unknown format' issue. I would like to perform recovery directly on python as it would be much more efficient

Comment: Please note that my answer suggests renaming + conversion, and you have tried just renaming. If you try it, it can work.

Comment: Use e.g. VLC to convert the file to WAV. The input  file format and file name don't matter.

Comment: pts, I've not explained myself completely as I also tried the combo renaiming + conversion. By the way I would need something less manual than VLC (if I understood correctly you are referring to the popular software and not to a relative python lib).

Comment: Instead of VLC, you can use ffmpeg to do an autmatic conversion. ffmpeg is a command-line tool, you can run it in a loop for all filenames.

Comment: If renaming + conversion (as described in this answer) doesn't work, that's extremely strange. You may want to attach a sample file (conversion input and output) to your question, without that it sounds impossible for us to help you.